# How to select file in subdirectory by "files" directive?

Tags: apache, file, .htaccess

I want to compile PHP code in specific .htm file, if file located at root directory of domain I can add

```
<Files file.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</Files>
```

to .htaccess, but what should I do if file located at another directory(/sub/file.htm, for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be done if your are using httpd 2.4 which has `<if>` supports

```
<If "%{PATH_INFO} =~ /.*\/sub\/(file|anotherfile|andanother)\.htm/">
   AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</If>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use the httpd.conf instead of .htaccess file. You could then use [`<Location>-directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) in this case:

```
<Location /sub/file.htm>
   AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</Location>
```

Note that if you want to use a regexp to match the location you need to write a `~` before the location or use the `<LocationMatch>-directive`.

E.g.:

```
<Location ~ "/sub/(file|anotherfile|andanother).htm">
   AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</Location>
```

**EDIT:**

Another possible solution (also only in virtualhost-config) should be a combined `<Directory>` and `<Files>`-directive:

```
<Directory /sub>
  <Files file.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I'm getting "500 Internal Server Error" because of it. tried this:
 <LocationMatch ~ "/sub/file.htm">
   AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch ~ "/home/user/subdomains/domain.com/sub/file.htm">
   AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</LocationMatch>

Comment: Request url is domain.com/sub/file.htm

Comment: `<Directory /sub>
  <Files file.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
  </Files>
</Directory>` Getting "500 Internal Server Error" with that too.

Comment: Files directive worked for me in .htaccess file if file.htm was located at root.

Comment: You tried to use Locationmatch with "~" in your first comment; thats wrong. Remove it and try again. You only need the ~ if you choose a directive without "match" in its name and want to use a regexp.

Answer (score -1):

Try FilesMatch:

```
<FilesMatch "file.htm$">
    AddType ...
</Files>
```

It applies a regex to the filename, so this'll match any file path which has "file.htm" at the end. It'd apply to any file in any directory that ends with "file.html". Note that this would also match on "somefile.htm" and "/subdir/somefile.htm". If you've got other files in your site tree that could trigger this, you'll have to mod the regex to exclude them.

Comment: Can I use name of directory in regex somehow to choose proper file?

Comment: Sure. filesmatch operators on the filesystem path of the file (not the requested url, but actually what apache's considering when it's talking to the server's filesystem), and that can include directories.

Comment: `<FilesMatch "\/sub\/file.htm">
    AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</FilesMatch>` Is that right?

Comment: If you're not using any wildcards/pattern stuff, then you could just use a regular `<files>` directive. The blackslashes in the path are also not necessary.

Comment: Tried `<Files /sub/file.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
</Files>` file didn't compiled.

Comment: Files-directive is only for files - you can't put a path in there.